# Booting from the flash Ubuntu Desktop 22.04.3 (created with Rufus) on Surface Pro 6

Tags: boot, uefi

I am aware of [Booting from the flash Ubuntu Studio 22.04 (created with Rufus) on Dell Vostro 15](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1461218/booting-from-the-flash-ubuntu-studio-22-04-created-with-rufus-on-dell-vostro-1?newreg=9f8d1f1d0cee4fd49410dbaf96e94b72)

Machine is currently running windows 11;

I have tried MBR, GPT, Fat32 and NTFS I have also tried to write the usb as DD mode as well. I have done it with Secure Boot on and off and also same with the TPM. I am maxed out here.

I have redownloaded Rufus cleared the appdata folder. I have redownloaded ubuntu to confirm its correct and even done the SHA check. Here is what Rufus reports as the 256. "a435f6f393dda581172490eda9f683c32e495158a780b5a1de422ee77d98e909"

Basically if I load Arch onto the same usb drive with secure boot turned off it launches into setup of Arch. If I have Ubuntu on there it gets stuck on the launching EFI\Boot. I am absolutely at my wits end on this and have no idea what to do.